# How to search a specific string in database in sqlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, search

I wanted to search for specific keyword existing in database and show them out.

Here's my code for search class:

```
String s = kw.getText().toString();

sqlhandler show = new sqlhandler(this);
show.open();
String rname = show.getName(s);
show.close();
tv.setText(rname);
```

And here's my database class:

```
public String getName(String kw) {

    String[] columns = new String[] {NAME, APRICE, DPRICE, VENDOR, KEYWORD };

    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, "DPRICE like " + "'%"+ kw+"%'", null, null, null, null);

    String sresult = "";

    int iname = c.getColumnIndex(NAME);
    int iap = c.getColumnIndex(APRICE);
    int idp = c.getColumnIndex(DPRICE);
    int ivendor = c.getColumnIndex(VENDOR);

    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
        sresult = sresult + c.getString(iname)+ " "+c.getString(iap)
            + "  " + c.getString(idp) + "  " + c.getString(ivendor)
        + "\n";
    }

    return sresult;
}
```

What is my problem here? I keep getting force close everytime I run it.

Comment: Post full exception stack.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't posted your LogCat I can only *guess*, but your WHERE clause looks suspicious:

```
"DPRICE like ..."
```

I assume `DPRICE` is a variable, not the actual column name:

```
DPRICE + " like ..."
```

---

Also I have a few recommendations:

- Use the `selectionArgs` parameter to prevent [SQL injection attacks](http://www.imperva.com/resources/glossary/sql_injection.html).
- Consider using a [ListView and SimpleCursorAdapter](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/simplecursoradapters-and-listviews/) to display your data.
- Only select the columns that you are using.
- Use a while-loop instead of a for-loop to iterate through your Cursor (your for-loop is doing three times the necessary work).

All together:

```
public String getName(String kw) {
    String[] columns = new String[] {NAME, APRICE, DPRICE, VENDOR};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, DPRICE + " like ?", new String[] {"'%" + kw + "%'"}, null, null, null, null);

    int iname = c.getColumnIndex(NAME);
    int iap = c.getColumnIndex(APRICE);
    int idp = c.getColumnIndex(DPRICE);
    int ivendor = c.getColumnIndex(VENDOR);

    // moveToNext() returns true when there is more data to read 
    //     or false when the cursor isAfterLast()
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        builder.append(c.getString(iname).append(" ")
               .append(c.getString(iap).append("  ")
               .append(c.getString(idp).append("  ")
               .append(c.getString(ivendor).append("\n");
    }

    return builder.toString();
}
```

Here is a [tutorial](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/simplecursoradapters-and-listviews/) on how to use a ListView with a custom layout to display information from a database.